# Can I show() a FragmentDialog after dismiss()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a FragmentDialog sppearing in front of a GoogleMap that I want to temporarily hide so that the user can select something on the background, and then bring it back in front again. Regular hide()/show() won't work since it's not "embedded" fragment, but a FragmentDialog cannot be hidden. I tried to use dismiss() and then show() using the same instance, since that should recreate the dialog, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Here's my code:

```
 if (onHoldDialog != null) {
        onHoldDialog.setPointText(mapMarker.getTitle());

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        onHoldDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Is my method wrong? Are FragmentDialog instances only "one-use"? Can I copy it to another instance?

Comment: I know that this is a very old post, but I too am having issues after doing a dismiss() then a show(). My issue is that the UI is being retained from the original dialog. No idea why, there is only one instance and I can see that I am setting the views which show as visible to the new image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was I overrode `onDismiss` in my `DialogFragment` subclass, but I didn't call `super.onDismiss`. Once I called the super's method, the problem was fixed.

In general, remember to call the super method of an overridden method in fragments and activities.